Trying to do a manual Ubuntu 24.04 install to have it encrypted and dual boot with Windows-10
I have just finished a manual Ubuntu 24.04 installation I did not reboot yet.
I couldn't find an option in this manual installation for encryption.  So I went back to the installation choice and clicked Advanced. There I chose LVL installation.  I don't understand why this Advanced option does not show on the Manual installation choice.
Anyway, I continued the installation by choosing manual installation and before it started doing the whole thing, when it shows what it will do, it was showing that it would do an LVM encryption.
But the thing is, I am at the end of the installation and no where was I asked for the encryption passphrase.
So it will encrypt it using what key?
Will it be an regular installation without encryption because there is passphrase key or will it generate one instead?
If it is generated, how will I know what it is?
I will do the reboot step and report here what happens next ....
[added comments]
Ok, I rebooted, entered my user log on and got to Desktop.  I did not see any messages about any kind of encryption.
I did a bit of internet search to see how can I tell if my disk is encrypted.  Did a few command, showed no encryption.  Last command I did is lsblk and did not show any encrypted disk anywhere.
I search for any videos that shows a manual installation with LVM and did not find any.
So am I to understand that choosing a manual installation will NEVER install an encrypted drive?
[Added comments]
I do not recall the name of the ISO I used.  BUt it was for Ubuntu desktop 64 that I installed on a USB key to create a live version.  I was trying to install through the 64 bits Ubuntu 24.04 Live version.
I found a workaround.

I deleted my Ubuntu partition (it was right after the Windows one)
moved a small windows block to the end of the free space
increase window's partition to the max of that free space
booted with my Ubuntu 24.04 live CD
cliques the Advanced button in the choice of installation and chose LVM encryption (there were 2 choices I think, I took the 2nd one)
at the end after rebooting, it did ask my passphrase and then my user logon
so it looks like I finally managed to have my encrypted Ubuntu.  What's left is to permanently encrypt another partition that I will use for Ubuntu backups and such


Ubuntu has used full disk partition for some time now; partition encryption was not as safe thus hasn't been used for many releases. Ubuntu 24.04 LTS is available using ubuntu-desktop-installer, subiquity (and for some flavors using calamares but you only mention release (24.04) and not which product/ISO you were using, thus what installer you used.
